# GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain | arm-none-eabi-gcc options: What is a difference between Thumb (-mthumb) and Arm (-marm) state?

Tags: arm, gnu-arm, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I have a maybe trivial question, but what is a difference between `Thumb (-mthumb)` and `Arm (-marm)` state and why most of the tutorials recommend to use `Thumb` state?

I am curious what exactly does it mean? What it is related to?

Best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to read those two articles, one from Arm, [Instruction Set Architecture](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets) (-marm means that GCC will generate arm32/A32 code, -mthumb means that it will generate thumb/T32 one), and this research paper, [Profile Guided Selection of ARM and ThumbInstructions](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Egupta/research/Publications/Comp/L14-krishnaswamy.pdf).

Basically, the two instruction sets differ in the set of instructions available as well as their encoding. You should therefore get a smaller and faster executable by using thumb/T32 than by using arm/A32.

This is the reason why most of the tutorials recommend to use the thumb/T32 instruction set.

Comment: This is what I meant! Huge thanks! I will read these articles for sure.